# How to make a Coq formalisation reusable?

Tags: coq

I'm working in a Coq formalisation of an algorithm. But components of this algorithm (some functions and lemmas) can be "overloaded" (in Haskell sense) on distinct types.

My intention is to avoid code duplication. I know that Coq has modules (like ML) and type classes (like Haskell). What is the best way to achieve reusability for lemmas and function definition in such a way it can be parameterised on distinct types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to avoid using Coq modules for doing anything other than namespacing or making definitions opaque. Dependent records (the underlying feature behind type classes) are better than modules in general for writing parametric definitions, because they are first-class objects that can be manipulated by the same rules that apply to other objects in Coq. That being said, when extracting Coq code into OCaml, Coq modules are extracted into OCaml modules, whereas dependent records rely on clever records to work properly. Thus, if you care about extracting into OCaml, and about interfacing with the extracted code, modules might be a better option.

Type classes are a feature built on top of dependent records for making them easier to use, by adding automatic instance inference. Unfortunately, type-class instance inference in Coq is not super robust, requiring you to tweak your instances or supply them by hand to get it to work in practice -- in any case, they are definitely harder to use than their Haskell counterparts -- and can also slow compilation time. The [MathClasses](https://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/MathClasses) library relies heavily on type classes for defining mathematical structures, and it seems to work well for them.

There is also another feature called canonical structures, which is also based on dependent records and accomplishes more or less the same as type classes, but with a slightly different programming model and inference engine. They work better than type classes in some cases, but are harder to use in others. The [Ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/) library uses them extensively, for instance.

There is a small discussion about using modules or records [here](https://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/ModulesNotRecords).